# Is there a literal suffix for 8 Bit values?

Tags: c, literals, xc8

I am working with the xc8 compiler and want to tell him that my literal is only 8 bit wide.

`123`      :no suffix, default int (16 bit in xc8)

`123U`     :unsigned int also 16 bit wide

Any idea for a clean solution to describe a 8 bit literal?

Comment: There are no standard suffixes for bytes. If you want a byte, then assign a suitable value to a byte-sized type (e.g. `int8_t`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 8 bit literals in C. The closest thing you can get is `UINT8_C(123)` from stdint.h, which gives you the literal most suitable for a variable of type `uint_least8_t`. Very likely it will expand to `123U`.

As for how to solve this practically, you show the constant into a define, which you should be doing anyway:

```
#define NUMBER_8BIT ( (uint8_t)123 )
```

Comment: A commonly used trick for such constants is to add a `+` such that it also may appear in preprocessor conditionals, something like `((uint8_t)+123)`.

Comment: I disagree that there are  no 8 bit literals in C.  Counter example: [`(uint8_t) { 123 }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50626361/2410359)

Comment: @chux Well formally they aren't called literals but integer constants. Literal was the term used by the OP so I kept it.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea for a clean solution to describe a 8 bit literal?

C only has 2 *literals*: *string literals* and *compound literals*  (C99).  C identifies `123` and `123u` as *integer constants*, not *literals*.

To form a C 8 bit literal: make a *compound literal*

```
#define OneTwoThree ((uint8_t) { 123 })
printf("%zu %x\n", sizeof(OneTwoThree), OneTwoThree);

// expected output
1 123
```

IDK if xc8 supports *compound literals*.

Answer (score 0):

Type convert to (unsigned char)